# How to fix( Zlib error : while decompressing data: inconsistent stream state )

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, zlib

I'm trying to run a file named "kiteplayer.sh" on Ubuntu, but I receive error message which I think is a problem with decompression.

```
>> $./kiteplayer.sh
```

but I recieve this message

```
>>  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/freekitesim/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1560, in _get
return self.loader.get_data(path)  
>>  zlib.error: Error -2 while decompressing data: inconsistent stream state
```

Comment: I don't understand what does `log file on bash` mean.

Comment: just trying to run this file "kiteplayer"